# mysql query using php limit records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question is how do I limit the number of records in this php query

```
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('a.*,b.category_name')
          ->from('#__p_list AS a')
          ->innerJoin('#__p_cat AS b ON b.id = a.category_id')        
          ->where('a.approved=1')
          ->where('a.published=1')
    ;

    $query->limits(8,0);  //This Portion not working
    $db->setQuery($query);
    return $db->loadObjectList();
```

I use

```
$query->limit(8,0);     //limit() and limits() both dun work
$query->limit(8);       //limit() and limits() both dun work
$query->setlimit(8,0);  //limit() and limits() both dun work
$query->setlimit(8);
$query->limit('8,0');
```

All doesn't work. Can someone please enlighten me

Comment: `$query->limits(0,8);`

Comment: What ORM or database query class are you using?

Comment: Oh I am using mysql. Strangely I tried $query->limits(0,8); don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

`limit(8,0)` means all records starting with the 8th record will be returned, so if you don't have 8 records mo records are returned. Using `limit (0,8)`, means 8 records starting with first record will be returned

also it seems your syntax is not correct, instead of:

```
$query->limits(8,0);  //This Portion not working
$db->setQuery($query);
```

use

```
$db->setQuery($query, 0,8);
```

Comment: funny using $query->limit(0,8); also doesn't limit

Comment: do you get records returned, without using limit?

Comment: Yes, all records are returned. When I add in the limit all records are also return without any error.

Comment: check the syntax of your database php framework, you are using once limits() and another time limit()

Comment: Hi Vickel, I am  not sure whether which is the correct spelling in this context, thats why I try everything with s and without s to see if it works. If in normal mysql statement it is just limit. But I never done something like $query->limit() before so not sure if it is correct.

Comment: that's why you need to look in the documentation of the query class to see what the correct syntax is

Comment: I suppose you need to use ->limit(8,0)

Comment: Thanks Vickel, I look around for documentation and it has to do with me using joomla. the correct way is $db->setQuery($query,0,8); to limit.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer, It has to do with me using joomla. The correct way to do it is add the limit at the point where you get the DB to execute the query.

```
$db->setQuery($query);
```

here you have to do this to limit

```
$db->setQuery($query,0,8);
```

Thanks everyone for helping.